# Conversion of ISO datetime string to pl.Datetime failure

Tags: datetime, timezone, iso8601, python-polars

I have a dataframe containing a timeseries, one column being ISO 8601 datetime strings of the form `2020-12-27T23:59:59+01:00`. This is a long running timeseries spanning multiple timezone offset changes due to DST (for reference, the data can be found [here](https://info.gesundheitsministerium.gv.at/data/COVID19_vaccination_timeline_v202210.csv)).

I try to parse those into `pl.Datetime` via `pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%+")`

This used to work but since version 0.15.7 of polars, this throws the following error:

`exceptions.ComputeError: Different timezones found during 'strptime' operation.`

I also tried a an explicit format string `fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"` which yields the same error.

Not sure if this is a bug or user error. I read the release notes for 0.15.7 on github and there are some mentions on ISo 8601 parsing, but but nothing that hints at why this would no longer work.

Comment: related [how to handle timestamps from summer and winter when converting strings in polars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75003869/10197418)

Comment: Interestingly, if I run `pl.Series(["2020-12-27T23:59:59+01:00", "2021-08-27T23:59:59+02:00"]).str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%+")`, on python-polars 0.15.16, I get no error, but the UTC offset seems to be ignored. If I change to `fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"`, I can reproduce the error.

Comment: yeah polars used to ignore the timezone before 0.15.7 when format was '%+'

Comment: I had a suspicion that the mixed offsets where the issue, but what threw me off was that it used to work. Assuming that no warning meant that everything would be parsed as expected was my undoing. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: So turns out I don't really need the tz offset info anyway as later on I merge with other data that is tz agnostic, and the data is also just sampled once per day, so I have opted to discard it. Nevertheless, thanks to both of you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6434/files

Previously, the timezone was ignored when parsing with `'%+'`. As of 0.15.17, it is respected.

In pandas, you could get around this by doing:

```py
In [22]: pd.to_datetime(dfp['date'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Vienna')
Out[22]:
0        2020-12-27 23:59:59+01:00
1        2020-12-27 23:59:59+01:00
2        2020-12-27 23:59:59+01:00
3        2020-12-27 23:59:59+01:00
4        2020-12-27 23:59:59+01:00
                    ...
255355   2023-01-25 23:59:59+01:00
255356   2023-01-25 23:59:59+01:00
255357   2023-01-25 23:59:59+01:00
255358   2023-01-25 23:59:59+01:00
255359   2023-01-25 23:59:59+01:00
Name: date, Length: 255360, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Vienna]
```

As of polars 0.16.0, you can do

```
pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%+", utc=True)
```

Comment: that requires knowledge of the origin time zone; also, `.str.split("+")` will fail for negative UTC offsets. Maybe parsing the offset [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75009041/10197418) would be a better work-around.

Comment: yeah I was just suggesting this as a solution to this particular dataset, you're right that it doesn't work in general. hopefully there will be a `utc` parameter in polars

Comment: @ignoring_gravity So you're already on it I see? :-)